# .htaccess solution for localhost

Tags: .htaccess, localhost

I am developing local websites and keep having problems with wordpress sites when they use relative links such as:

```
<a href="/wp-content/themes/mytheme/myfile.php">
```

This resolves to my localhost document root (htdocs) instead of the root of the job (htdocs/myjob).

Is it possible to use an .htaccess file in the root of the job (htdocs/myjob) folder to "fix" this behaviour? Or is it possible to put this htaccess file in htdocs, check the HTTP_REFERER, and send the browser to the correct site root?

Can you show me an example of the rewrite rule needed?

Any other suggestions would be welcome too.

Answer (score 0):

In fact you mean *absolute* links. Relative links are what you want.

You should be able to configure the root directory in your Wordpress setup: this would be the correct approach.